# Where can i move this r markdown code?

Tags: r

I hope this is in the correct forum. I am working on a project for a [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/statistical-inference).

I have this code (please see below) near the top of my .Rmd file and it knitr's just fine.

I need to make the output shorter (course requirement), so i was thinking of putting the code into an init function. Should one do this? Will it work?

I need the code to be run up front. I do want to show the code in the knitr document, but i would like to be in the appendix with the other code,

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: looks like everything but the source can go into a function.

````
```{r}
#install.packages('e1071')  # do once in R console.
library(e1071) 
source("functions.R")
set.seed(1)
initialize()
```
````

Edit2: the code is now smaller:

`{r}
source("functions.R")
initialize()`

Comment: Try the RStudio community forums https://community.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to run but don't want it included set include=FALSE as shown below

````
```{r pressure, include=FALSE}
TYPE CODE HERE
```
````